# MVCGrid.Net How can I inject a service in the MVCGridConfig class using Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

I use Ninject as a dependency injector for my ASP.Net MVC application.

However, MVCGridConfig is a static class.

How can I inject my ICoursesService in the MVCGridConfig class in order to retrieve the necessary data for the table?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, this was the correct things to do. if you want to you can post it as an answer so that I can choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to inject into a static class, but you could pull it using

```
var svc = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICoursesService>();
```